# Unexpected behavior of a Winforms label

Tags: winforms

I am working on a Windows Forms application and I would like someone to explain why the problem I'm encountering happens. The problem is that a label whose text I set at the beginning of a function changes (apparently) at the end of the function.
I have the following code:

```
private void OnButtonSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelLoading.Text = "Loading...";
    dataGridViewSearchResults.DataSource = listOfFilteredEntities();
            
}
```

My filtering function gets a list of entities from the database and filters them by parameters passed to the function.
The problem is that the label text becomes visible after the datagridview displays the results. I'm not using background threads which might change the label text. Thank you.

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]. You've obviously left something crucial out.

Comment: You need to make the DB loading function async and await on it. Otherwise your form has no chance of redraw itself because of the main thread being blocked.

Comment: Or `labelLoading.Text = "Loading..."; labelLoading.Refresh();`, if you want to keep the procedure synchronous and show the new text.

Comment: How could I implement async filtering? If I change the filtering function's signature to `Task<List<myObject>> Filter()`, I am getting a warning stating that it lacks an await, although I am awaiting it (maybe incorrectly). What would be the best approach? I want to make as little changes as possible to the code. As you can probably tell, I'm new to asynchronous programming.

Comment: I solved the issue by using the BackgroundWorker component. Thanks to everyone trying to help.